# Dealing with data stored as JSON objects in a MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'm using opencart 2.1 and one of the field on the customer table is an text array. The data field (named custom, type text) look like this:
`{"2":"2015","1":"2000-11-19"}`
Basically, the 1st part is a birthday (not allow null), and the second part is today year (allow null). It was saved to the database using serialize($arr)

I need a query to get the data based on the "birthday" part.
Basically, it's something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE MONTH(custom.1) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(custom.2) = DAY(NOW())
```

I don't know how to refer to part 1 or part 2 of the custom field. If I can get the query to work, I can bring it back to php and use $arr = unserialize($arr) to fetch it into an array and use it.

Also, later on, I would need to update the part 2 of the custom field (aka, the "this year" part. It can be null, or last year, and need to be update to this year). How could I do that and still keep the part 1 (aka, birthday) the same?

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)? You'll have to pull that result as the String it is.

Comment: Unless you can use Mysql 5.7, and change the type of the column, *and* that's okay with the cart software, then you'll have to use string comparison against the whole string, not just a part of it. Or, use `LIKE` to look for unique parts -- not very reliable. It is not, generally, good practice to store data in this fashion because, as you have experienced, it is difficult to include in queries. I know you didn't set it up that way, but you're learning the lesson from someone else's mistake.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with json_decode, and can't use Mysql 5.7. can you give me more detail on how to use json_decode in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You could update to `MySQL 5.7` where `JSON` column field types are now supported.

So your query would look like this:

`SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE MONTH(jsn_extract(custom,"$.1")) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(jsn_extract(custom,"$.2")) = DAY(NOW())`

---

**Solution 2:**

Query the data normaly and filter your needed result with PHP functions - like the JSON Decode + DateTime classes.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

---

**Solution 3:**

You could use the MySQL functions like `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to extract your values directly from the `JSON`. But this leads to strange errors when the data structure is changing and is not very fail safe.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with json_decode, and can't use Mysql 5.7. can you give me more detail on solution how to use json_decode in this case? Thanks!

Comment: So I was able to do it with the `substring_index`, and it's quite messy. But if there is no other way for the moment, I might have to go with it. `SELECT * FROM 'rwy_customer' WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(custom_field,'-',-2),'-',1) = MONTH(NOW()) AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(custom_field,'-',-1),'"',1) = DAY(NOW())`